# Hyperloop and standard CommonJS project

Tags: ios, appcelerator, commonjs, hyperloop, appc-hyperloop

I tried to use Hyperloop in a non-Alloy project and apparently it doesn't work (please, correct me if I'm wrong). Is there any technical reason why a traditional CommonJS project can't make use of Hyperloop?

Answer (score 1):

A classic project created with `ti create` and then imported with `appc new --import` to get hyperloop compiles fine.

```
var Activity = require('android.app.Activity');
var Context = require("android.content.Context");
var activity = new Activity(Titanium.App.Android.getTopActivity());

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});

win.open();
```

nothing special but it is a hyperloop project running in an classic environment without any problem

Comment: Ok, but my case is different: I create anything using Studio (is there any possible difference? It stops working just before xcodebuild, on iOS)

Comment: "Requirements

You’ll need to have the following minimum requirements to use Hyperloop for iOS"

    Titanium 5.4.0+
    Alloy 1.8.0+   https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Hyperloop

Comment: I was testing Android on Linux